# How to run pocketsphinx from Windows CMD

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, pocketsphinx

I am currently following the tutorial on cmusphinx.sourceforge.net to install pocketsphinx for Windows. Admittedly I only have experience in C#, and I'm not at all familiar with DOS commands.

My problem: When I try to run pocketsphinx_continuous, either through command prompt or by clicking on the icon, a DOS window pops up, quickly scrolls through a bunch of text, then closes before I can read anything on it. I'm not sure what to do.

My system: Windows 7 64-bit

What I've done:

I downloaded off the CMU sourceforge website the following: sphinxbase-5prealpha, pocketsphinx-5prealpha.

I unpacked both folders onto my desktop.

I went into the sphinxbase folder, opened sphinxbase.sln in Visual Studio 2012, then built the project.

I then went into the pocketsphinx folder, opened pocketsphinx.sln in Visual Studio 2012, and built the project.

I copied sphinxbase.dll from sphinxbase/bin/Release/Win32 and pasted it into pocketsphinx/bin

I tried clicking on pocketsphinx_continuous.exe. I get the problem.

I tried running in cmd `C:\Users\*my name*\Desktop\pocketsphinx\bin\Release\Win32\pocketsphinx_continuous.exe -inmic yes -hmm model\en-us\en-us -lm model\en-us\en-us.lm.bin -dict model\en-us\cmudict-en-us.dict`. Same problem.

I tried putting sphinxbase.dll in pocketsphinx/bin/Release/Win32. Same problem.

I tried doing all this for the files in pocketsphinx/bin/Release/x64

I tried doing all this for the files in pocketsphinx/bin/Debug/Win32(or x64)

I also tried building the projects in Visual Studio 2015, same problem.

I'm hoping I'm just making some blatant mistake, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also googled around for a couple hours, and it just seems like the documentation on installing for Windows 7 is very sparse.

Comment: You need to run the command from cmd from the pocketsphinx root folder. You need to make sure the paths you specify in command line arguments are correct. If you are not sure what relative path is, specify an absolute path to the data files.

Comment: If you need more help, provide cmd output